# Combining multiple UPDATE, SET statements into one textstring from SysColumns table

Tags: sql, sql-server

I have a lot of columns in SQL Server 2016, where I need to substitute NULL values and 'NULL values with '' values. And it is a monthly job, that requires to run from a frontend application (button). Therefore I need my update function to be converted to one long textstring, so it's a ready-use script, that can be run without backend interference.

So far, I'm able to get the update statements right, but I need them joined together within SQL in one textstring or something like that, so they can be run as one script. My table is called 'test' in this example.

```
DECLARE @NULL AS VARCHAR(50)
SET @NULL = 'NULL'

SELECT ' UPDATE [test] SET [' + name + '] = '''' WHERE [' + name + '] IS NULL OR [' + name + '] = '''+@Null+''' ' FROM syscolumns
WHERE id =OBJECT_ID('test')
AND isnullable =1
```

This code gives me this output:

```
        (No column name)
     1   UPDATE [test] SET [id] = '' WHERE [id] IS NULL OR [id] = 'NULL' 
     2   UPDATE [test] SET [name] = '' WHERE [name] IS NULL OR [name] = 'NULL' 
     3   UPDATE [test] SET [date] = '' WHERE [date] IS NULL OR [date] = 'NULL' 
     4   UPDATE [test] SET [address] = '' WHERE [vejnavn] IS NULL OR [vejnavn] = 'NULL' 
     5   ... Multiple extra columns that needs to be updated
```

What I'm looking for, is that all these rows are combined into 1 long row... Something like this, so it's possible to update all columns in one go. AS it's a system table, I haven't been able to come up with a good solution for concatenating these multiple rows into one and executing it as a script yet.

```
  UPDATE [test] SET [id] = '' WHERE [id] IS NULL OR [id] = 'NULL'     UPDATE [test] SET [name] = '' WHERE [name] IS NULL OR [name] = 'NULL'  UPDATE [test] SET [date] = '' WHERE [date] IS NULL OR [date] = 'NULL'
```

Comment: You'd be much better off creating a stored procedure for your maintenance and then calling it from your client app.

Answer (score 0, accepted):

I managed to find a solution by having a support-table where I Insert all the update lines into. Thereafter I join these rows together using XML FOR PATH and calls all the rows via a @Query call like this:

```
CREATE TABLE Test3 (Columns varchar(5000))

DECLARE @NULL AS VARCHAR(50)
SET @NULL = 'NULL'

TRUNCATE TABLE TEST3
INSERT INTO TEST3 (Columns )
SELECT 'UPDATE [test] SET [' + name + '] = '''' WHERE [' + name + '] IS NULL OR [' + name + '] = '''+@Null+''' ' FROM syscolumns
WHERE id =OBJECT_ID('test')
AND isnullable =1

DECLARE @Query as VARCHAR(5000)
SELECT @Query = STUFF((SELECT ' ' + Columns FROM TEST3 FOR XML PATH ('')), 1, 1, '') FROM TEST3

EXEC (@Query)
```

Answer (score 0):

Well, the logic is a but cumbersome, but:

```
UPDATE [test]
    SET [id] = COALESCE(NULLIF(id, 'NULL'), ''),
        [name] = COALESCE(NULLIF(name, 'NULL'), ''),
        . . .
    WHERE NULLIF(id, 'NULL') IS NULL OR
          NULLIF(name, 'NULL') IS NULL OR
          . . .;
```

The use of functions in the `WHERE` clause generally prevents the use of indexes.  However, as a single query, this is really going to require a full table scan regardless.